# Issues Referencing an Image In ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I hope you're holding on in these hard times. I'm building a React app but by configuring the webpack first. So, I'm trying to use an image by importing it or referencing it in the image tag but it's not working as it should. May anyone please tell me what I'm doing worng? Thanks in advance.

**My webpack file**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js', 
  output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
      filename: 'index_bundle.js',
      publicPath: 'dist'
  }, 
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: './dist', 
    port: 8080
 },
 performance: {
  hints: 'warning',
  maxEntrypointSize: 400000

},
  module:  {
      rules: [
            {
              test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, 
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              use: [
                  {loader: 'babel-loader'},
                ]
              },
              {
                test: /\.css$/,
                 use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
              },
              {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
                use:{
                  loader: 'url-loader',
                }
              },
              {
                resolve: {
                  alias: {
                    public: path.join(__dirname, '/public')
                  }
                }
              }
          ]
  },

  plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: './index.html'
      })
  ]
}
```

**My Navbar file**

```
import { NavbarBrand, Navbar, NavLink } from 'reactstrap';
import logo from '../public/clean_boy';


const imageStyle={
    height: "60px",
    width: "100%",
    padding: "20px 20px -10px 10px",
    marginRight: "10px"
}
const NavBar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar dark color="dark">
                <NavbarBrand href="/" className="fluid"><img src={logo} style={imageStyle}/>Domestic Workers</NavbarBrand>
                <NavLink href="#">Log In</NavLink>
            </Navbar>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NavBar;
```

**Server Error**

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../public/clean_boy' in '/Users/moise.rwibutso/Andela - Sims Apps/Domestic-workers-system/UI/components'
 @ ./components/NavBar.js 3:0-39 19:9-13
 @ ./components/App.js
 @ ./index.js
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a file extension for `clean_boy`? Something like `import logo from '../public/clean_boy.png'`

Comment: @JuanMarco, thanks a lot. It's funny how it didn't work before with the .png extension but not it works by adding the .svg extension.

Comment: Is it an svg file? Anyway, happy to help.